# How to remove <!doctype html> from document with cheerio.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<?xml ...>` from a html document parsed by cherio.js. Is it possible to do it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>text</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply extract the html. All you need to do is to add the html tags again

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const html = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>text</div>
  </body>
</html>
`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($('html').html());
```

Comment: Ok, that make sense. I was just messing around with `gulp-cheerio` library which made this step impossible but I noticed it's only small wrapper I can provide nevertheless. Thank you.

Comment: alternatively you could `const $outer = cheerio.load(html); const $ = cheerio.load($outer('html').html()); console.log($.html())`